# how to disable angularjs $resource.get is auto sort?

Tags: angularjs

I have an API which is return json object like this

```
"keyStoreTypes":{"NONE":"None","JKS":"JKS","PKCS12":"PKCS12"}
```

But $resource.get is auto sorting it like this

```
$resource.get('/to/url').$promise

"keyStoreTypes":{"JKS":"JKS", "NONE":"None","PKCS12":"PKCS12"}
```

Comment: Objects have no order so this is an XY Problem. How is data being used?

Comment: I am using it to fill values in dropdown.

Comment: Either send as array or map to array in controller

Comment: add property "position" in each object and order in a tpl by this property

Comment: and better use array to store values in keyStoreTypes, like this [{name : 'JKS', label 'JKS', position : 1}]